# jasper exception. The Struts dispatcher cannot be found

Tags: java, struts2

I have two JSP files:

- `index.jsp` (with no Struts 2 tags)
- `login.jsp` (with Struts 2 tags)

I have linked to `login.jsp` to `index.jsp` with `<a href="login.jsp">LOGIN IN</a>` tag.

When clicked the page doesn't load, instead throws the error:

```
(ERROR:org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.).
```

If all the struts tag are removed from `login.jsp` it works fine.

**web.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
        <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

How to run my application with Struts 2 tags on it?

Answer (score 0):

If there are S2 tags on a page it must be reached via an action.

S2 tags expect data from the framework.